# Convert Text string to the same numeric in both environments: SQL Oracle g11 <--> Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am looking for standard SQL functions in Oracle g11 SQL and Sql Server 2008 to accomplish the following; convert a textual string to a number/integer. Same string should result in same number in both environments. I know there are hashfunctions (but they result in alphanumeric results) and checksum functions.

A good answers contains a working example with standard SQL functions for both DB's.

### Oracle

select Oracle_function_I_search ('ABCD')
from xxx

results in an integer/numeric: for example "4558994"

### SQL server

select SQLserver_function_I_search ('ABCD')
from xxx

results in the SAME integer/numeric:  "4558994"

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You want to convert alphabetic characters to numbers? Any particular logic required to the conversion or do you just want a function to convert the characters consistently?

Comment: This sounds a LOT like homework to me. Can you explain why the string ABCD becomes the integer 4558994? There is no correlation there that is immediately obvious. What have you tried?

Comment: I want to do the same thing as discussed in question 8810471. But go one step further; create a numeric instead of a hexadecimal.

Comment: 4558994 is only an example; I just expect a numeric. Tried already a lot of things; but I am always stuck in one of both DB's. Thanks for your help.